# C# Find Places an Abstract Class is used

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, dependencies

I had an abstract class Foo.  I want to get a list of classes that derive from it.  All my searches are returning how to do it via code, and really I'm just wondering if there's some built in feature of VS that will do it for me... seems simple enough just to get a list for non-programming purposes.  Thanks

Comment: Tools like resharper shows the deriving or implementing class navigation from base class.

Comment: If you have resharper, you can right click on your class and then click "Find Usages Advanced"

Comment: You could always just change the class name (manually, not via Rename... or other automated refactoring methods) and see where the errors are.

Comment: @helrich It will report error in cases where it has used like created object of base class. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VS2012 Solution Explorer expand the file icon, right click the abstract class and click *Derived Types*.

Alternatively open the class in *Class View*, right click and *Show Derived Classes*.

Comment: Perfect, I knew it must be simple.  Will accept as soon as I'm allowed to.  thanks

Answer (score 1):

Go to the abstract class, right click on the class name and select option "Find All References".

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the name of your class and choose *Find all references*.